# Sequential Keras model is able to predict different size of input?

Tags: python, keras, nlp, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am new to recurrent networks and nlp. I try to create a text generation model. First I padded my sequences in order to prevent shape mismatch during training:

```
[1505,  422,   63,  324],
[   7,   63,    7,    0],
[ 201,   16,   63,  201],
```

My model is:

```
    model3 = Sequential()
#model3.add(Input(3,))
model3.add(Embedding(1614, 20, input_length=3))
model3.add(LSTM(50,return_sequences=True))
model3.add(LSTM(50))
model3.add(Dense(1614,activation='sigmoid'))
model3.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

model3ecod.fit(x_cod,y_cod, epochs =20,batch_size=10)
```

After training, I try to predict next word of given vector, for example,:

np.argsort(model3.predict( np.array([[63,7,63]])))[0][-1:]

returns,0 as expected;

However I noticed that I can even predict [63,7,63,0,124,.... ]] or even single sequences [[63,]]. The accuracy seems low, but however It looks strange to me and made me suspect if my model is wrong? The LSTM layers should only take fixed size of input isn't it? Then how the model is able to predict different size of input than training data?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Try the code by enabling these two options then it will throw an error, `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` and `tf.data.experimental.enable_debug_mode()` the reason is by default TensorFlow uses graph execution when it is doing tracing process, but when you enable the eager execution no more tracing is done then it will throw an error. With only one element it will not throw an error because the model takes the one element as batch_1. but other than that it will throw the error.

Comment: thanks.. but it is also predict when i give longer sequences than 3(which is input for the model)

Comment: first clear your keras layers memory. by doing `keras.backend.clear_session()` then run the model again with eager execution.

Comment: It does now ! Slower training process tough :( even if the batch size = 1, the input inside of this batch is a single element, how model gives prediction on one element if it is trained on 3 sequences? thanks a lot :)

Comment: This mode is only on when you wanna try to debug your code... Well, try to understand the `tf.keras.layers.Embedding()` .